# Excel VBA leading zero's are not displaying

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel column where the digits count should be 4. The data is copying from 1 sheet to other.
Previous sheet is in text/General format. But pasting sheet is copying as special I have wrote a code as below:

```vb
Range("G6:G" & lastrow).Select 
Selection.NumberFormat = "0000"
```

With the above code I was able to get leading 0's but once I click on the column that leading 0's are not showing and displaying format as special. But business wants it in "General". Because of this issue the calculations are not matching.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why not `Range("G6:G" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "0000"`?

Comment: I tried that as well as below:  Range("B6:B" & lastrow).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0000" so with this zeros are coming as special =. once i click on any column then 0's are not showing up

Comment: SIde note: [You don't need to Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Main note: it depends whether you have true numbers, or numbers stored as text.

Comment: Let me try like this Range("G6:G" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "0000". will let you know

Comment: It is still taking as special. column display is 001 but once i click on it, it is showing as 1.

Comment: Do you mean it shows as 1 in the formula bar because with Numberformat you're only changing how it looks to a user, not its initial value. If you want it to look like `0001` for the cell and the formula bar, you'll need to change its actual value to it. If you had leading 0's in the one sheet, use `.Numberformat = "@"` to make it as text before you paste (not after).

Comment: Like I said, you can use something like `Range("C5:C" & lastrow).Numberformat = "@"` prior to that copy paste. Putting a full paste of your code in a comment is hard to read and gets lost to other readers, edit your question to add it at the bottom. Remember what BigBen said, you don't need to use Select.

Comment: Nothing is working. Still getting in special format

Comment: Either you have a number in the cell with a custom format, in which case the zeroes are virtual, or you have text in the cell with actual materialized zeroes - but in that case the format will still have be "Text". Because if you set it to "General" your zeroes will only live until someone edits that cell. You cannot have leading zeroes and keep the format as General. Nor should you.

Comment: @GSerg So im copying data from one sheet to another. Copying data is in text. but, paste data is converting as special where leading 0's are missing.

Comment: Format the target cells as "Text" before copying?

Comment: thats what im doing.

Comment: Show us your full code (in your question this time) so we can see where it's going wrong. Some sample data to work with couldn't hurt either, see [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel and edit it into your question.